MVVM Toolkit: A View Model containing an Observable Validator
Usually, a ViewModel (VM) can inherit from a ObservableValidator:
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableValidator 
{ ... }

But I want to have a VM and want to isolate the validation inside the VM into an internal ObservableValidator:
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
     [ObservableProperty] private Validator _validator;
} 

where
public partial class Validator : ObservableValidator
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [Required]
    private string _name;
}

This is promising, I've bind properly, the properties are being updated, all is honky dory.
The problem is that at validation time:
 [RelayCommand]
 private void Unfocused(EventArgs eventArgs)
 {
    var visualElement = ((FocusEventArgs)eventArgs).VisualElement;
    var text = ((Entry)visualElement).Text;
    var prop = visualElement.StyleId;

    Validator.ValidateProperty(text, prop);
  ...}

I can't access the ValidateProperty method because it's protected:
protected internal void ValidateProperty(object? value,
                     [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null!)
{...}

My questions are:
Is it possible or advisable to have an ObservableValidator inside the ViewModel
Or
How can I workaround the ValidateProperty method without overriding it?.
I tried overriding the method but don't want to break the code.
